# Save Array or List of values to Redis cache

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I'm attemptign to use Redis cloud and push an Array of String values using below code:

```
import com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisClient;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisURI;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.api.StatefulRedisConnection;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.api.sync.RedisCommands;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class WriteToRedis {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExchangeCurrencyPairScenario.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient(
                RedisURI.create("redis://****@cloud.redislabs.com:15162"));
        StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = redisClient.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected to Redis");
        RedisCommands<String, String> syncCommands = connection.sync();
        syncCommands.rpush("key" , new String[]{"Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda"});
        connection.close();
        redisClient.shutdown();
}
```

But receive exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandExecutionException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.LettuceFutures.await(LettuceFutures.java:127)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.LettuceFutures.awaitOrCancel(LettuceFutures.java:96)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.FutureSyncInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FutureSyncInvocationHandler.java:61)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.internal.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.rpush(Unknown Source)
    at com.reactive.api.redis.WriteToRedis.main(WriteToRedis.java:39)
```

I can save String values and connect to the Redis cloud cache with no issue. But it seems I have not configured the format of the value associated with the "key" correctly? How to correctly persist and Array (or List) of values to a Redis cache using Java?

Comment: Found this Jedis example that might be helpful
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_java.htm

search by "Redis Java List Example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis operates by [data types](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro).

Use of `rpush` in your code implies that you're trying to use [RPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/rpush) command which is part of [List](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-lists) data type.

You're trying to operate on a key named `key` and getting following error:

```
WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

Which means your Redis instance/DB already contains data in `key` key and the data type of existing data is something other than List.

If you want to know the data type of data contained against a key, you can use [TYPE](https://redis.io/commands/type) command. E.g. to check `key` key:

```
syncCommands.type("key");
```

You can use [DEL](https://redis.io/commands/del) command to delete that data. E.g.

```
syncCommands.del("key");
```